# How do you install Conan CLI using Python?

Tags: python, conan

I read the [installation page of Conan](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html), but I just couldn't figure out how do I get the CLI when installing using *pip* ?

I ran `pip install conan` and now I have the `conans` directory in my `<virtual-env>/Lib/site-packages-conans`, but from what I see it's only Python sources, I don't see how do I get the Conan CLI available?

### EDIT

Thanks to @drori, I found that when I `pip install conan` in a virtual environment, the `conan.exe` is installed in the `Scripts` directory which is added to the `PATH`.

But when running `pip install` NOT in a `venv`, the `Scripts` directory in `%APPDATA%` is not automatically added to the PATH.

Anyway, this detail was worth mentioning in the docs IMHO.

Comment: `pip install conan` also creates a ``conan`` executable in the current venv, so just running ``conan`` in your terminal should work. If it doesn't, something went wrong with the ``pip install`` and probably the best is report it in Gitub issues, specifying OS, python version and architecture, pip version, output of ``pip install conan``, etc

Comment: You mean it should be added to the PATH of the current shell?

Comment: Yes, exactly, under a venv, the PATH contains something like ``C:\Users\<user>\Envs\conan36\Scripts`` in the first place (this is in Windows, different of course in other OS), and that folder contains ``conan.exe`` executable.